How to get IIS to access files on a DFS without connecting as a specific-user?
I'd like some clarification on a few things related to IIS and Distributed File Systems.
Before anything, let me provide a bit of context.
So, we have this old ASP.NET web site that is basically just a front-end for a MySQL database, and it's being hosted by IIS on a Windows Server 2022 VMWare server.
We have a DFS that stores, among other things, documents that are related to the ASP.NET site.
All our domain users have a mapped drive on their machine (the i drive), which is mapped via a batch file, and access to the various parts of the DFS is handled through a web interface provided to us by our IT provider, not through the security settings in a folders properties window. Attempting to change permissions in the regular way will simply result in errors being thrown.
So, the only way I have been able to get things to work is if I set up IIS so that it connects as a "Specific User" for both the site and its virtual directories. And the same account is used as the "Custom Account" for the Application Pool Identity. When I do this I am able to get the links to work with the documents on the DFS, however I don't like this as I am using my domain user account for this, which I feel is not the best idea. Not to mention, we have a ridiculous password policy where we are forced to change them quite regularly, which means that every time I have to change my password, I have to also update it in IIS.
What I want to know is, how can I get this to work without using my user account to connect?
I thought that perhaps I could grant permissions to the DFS to the "Computer" instead of a user or group, but I can't test this idea because the interface we have been given to grant permissions to folders in the DFS doesn't have the option of adding different "object types" to search for the way you do through the security settings in a folders properties window. And by default it only searches for Users and Groups and Built-in Security Principles, so I can't grant permission to a "Computer".
But would this actually work? If I could grant permission to the "Computer" that is hosting the web site would I be able to go back to using pass-through authentication and the built-in ApplicationPoolIdentity?
Another thing I'd like to know is, what account is being used when you have it set to use pass-through and have the App Pools Id set to the built-in ApplicationPoolIdentity? Is it using IUSR? If permissions for the DFS folders are granted to the IIS_IUSRS group would that perhaps work?
Could somebody please enlighten me as to how this all works, and let me know what I am doing wrong and how to go best go about it. Is my concern for using my user account justified? How would you go about doing this?
Edit
Is the IIS_IUSRS groups specific to each computer? The reason I ask this is because when I look at the permissions for the wwwroot folder on my machine it includes "myHostname\IIS_IUSRS".
If this is the case then would permission on the DFS folders need to be given to "serverHostname\IIS_IUSRS"?
Sorry if this is a stupid question...

Many have been answered in https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

are you creating and using virtual folders on that site? And do you need to? I would consider creating one user, even a AD one for the app-pool that has rights to those folders. And you don't need a virtual folder either. Remember, code behind uses plain jane windows path names. So, code behind can read those files regardless if you have any virtual folders or not. Virtual folders are ONLY for valid URL's, but that does not apply to code behind. So, code behind can use valid UNC path names to those files for display, or downloading or whatever, and without virtual folders, it far more secure

Yes, there are virtual folders being used, because the paths are used as hyperlinks in a table with databound values. Creating a single user for the sole purpose of running this site and accessing the files was on my list of fallback solutions but I really didn't want to be using an account that would have to have it's password changed regularly as all our AD accounts have strict password rules..
